# sqlite python import just selected columns

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

I have a folder with *hundreds* of csv files with 9 values from a temperature sensor in it. The columns are sensor_id, lat, lon (for the coordinates) and some other stuff that i don't need. The columns that i ***need*** are ***just*** the ***three*** [timestamp, temperature and humidity].

1. I already tried to use a module to import just the columns that i want and
2. i tried to delete the columns that i dont want with loops.

slowly i despair, can someone help me pls?

Comment: Can you edit your post with an example of the data, just one line will work? Also, do the files have a heading line at the top that should be ignored?

Comment: CSV is a text format, really, so there's no way around reading the entire row. But, you can just ignore the fields you aren't interested in.

What's the actual problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to use Pandas, you can do it simply by using `usecols` parameter, while reading the csv file.

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_file/path/file.csv', usecols=['col1', 'col2']) 
print(df.shape)
df.head()
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'pd' has no attribute 'read_csv'

my file is called csv_test.py, so there can't be a conflict

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that should do it, just add in your target directory and change the numbers on the last line to the index of the column you want (with the first column being 0):

```py
import os
import csv

targetdir = "" # fill this in
allrows = []

files = os.listdir(targetDir)
for file in files:
    with open('innovators.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            allrows.append([row[1], row[3], row[5]])
```

Comment: allrows.append([row[1], row[3], row[5]])

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Can you send an example of a line from your data?

Comment: import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('pandasimportssss.db')
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\name\Desktop\v3\2020-09-01_sds011_sensor_3659.csv', sep=';')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['timestamp', 'P1', 'P2'])
print(df)
df.to_sql(name='sds011', con=conn)

That worked now

Comment: Now i'm working at the loop for the directory, but i dont work as well

(startdate = timestamp from 25.09.2020 and enddate timestamp 24.09.2021)

while startdate <= enddate:
    date = datetime.fromtimestamp(startdate).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    startdate += 86400  # 1 day = 86400 sec

    data = pd.read_csv(f'C:/Users/myname/Desktop/v3/sds011/{datum}_sds011_sensor_3659.csv', sep=';')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['timestamp', 'P1', 'P2'])
    df.to_sql(name='sds011', con=conn)

Do you know a solution?

Comment: I meant a line out of your CSV, not your code. Without knowing the format of the csv, it's impossible to know which columns you want to extract

Comment: sensor_id;sensor_type;location;lat;lon;timestamp;P1;durP1;ratioP1;P2;durP2;ratioP2
3659;SDS011;18XX;XX.482;X.224;2019-12-31T00:00:41;6.67;;;5.40;;
3659;SDS011;18XX;XX.482;X.224;2019-12-31T00:03:10;10.80;;;5.30;;
durP1, ratioP1, durP2 and ratioP1 are empty

sensor type is a number with 4 digits (i censored it, the coordinates also)